# SWIG: private typedefs used in public functions

Tags: c++, typedef, swig

I often give my classes a private typedef to refer to themselves, as follows:

```
class MyClass {
  private:
    typedef MyClass Self;
  public:
    void DeepCopyFrom(const Self& other);
    ...
};
```

I'm now wrapping my C++ code using SWIG, which complains about such typedefs:

```
error: ‘typedef class MyClass MyClass::Self’ is private
```

The wrapper code that causes this error looks like:

```
SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_MyClass_DeepCopyFrom(PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), PyObject *args) {
  PyObject *resultobj = 0;
  MyClass *arg1 = (MyClass *) 0 ;
  MyClass::Self *arg2 = 0 ;
  (...)
```

The compiler error happens on that last line, above the ellipsis.

Is there any way to tell SWIG to not use private typedefs, and instead just use the full type name?

Comment: why not just make the typedef public

Comment: I could do that, but I was wondering if there's a SWIG-side solution, as in, something I can write in the .i interface file. This is partly because I don't  consider the "Self" typedef to be part of the external interface. Partly, this is in preparation for when I face this situation with code I can't immediately change (e.g. other peoples' code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest keeping it simple(r): just remove the typedefs and write the class name instead.

If you really hate that, you could tell SWIG to `%ignore` the "broken" methods and then `%extend` the classes with wrapper methods calling the real ones.  Unless the number of classes and methods you are binding is small relative to your total codebase, this cure is probably worse than the disease.

Answer (score 1):

SWIG by default will not process any typedef or declaration or anything in a `private` section. Therefore, it assumes (when it sees `const Self&`) that `Self` is some unknown type from a header or something else, it leaves it as such and generates wrapper code with the `Self` left in there. The problem is that this wrapper code is a function external to the class, and since `MyClass::Self` is private, your compiler generates an error. I've had the same thing happen to my code: what I had to do was either declare the typedef in a `public` section or to rewrite `Self` as `MyClass`. Changing the typedef to `public` makes the most sense to me.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it explained what was going on in SWIG-land. You say that "SWIG **by default** will not process (...) anything in a private section." (emphasis added.) Do you know if there a way to tell it to?

Comment: @Super: I wrote "by default" because I wasn't absolutely sure that it was the only option, but on reviewing the SWIG documentation again, I believe it is: you're just going to have to make it `public`.

Answer (score 0):

I have rarely if ever seen a private typedef, but I guess there is nothing wrong with it with respect to the idea of encapsulation. However, if you have a public function which uses the typedef, then doesn't that make the typedef part of your interface?

I would imagine that you could use a private typedef inside some member functions or private member function interfaces. But if you want to use it on a public method, it only makes sense that the typedef be public as well.

I don't know what the standard says about the subject, but I would guess it is one of the few gray areas. I would assume that it is dependent on the compiler's implementation on how to handle typedefs in a class that you determine if it is even acceptable to use a private typedef in a public method (or even acceptable at all). To be safe, I would just make it public.

If you are worried about exposing the typedef, then don't use it in any public member function's prototype (and still that might be rejected by some compiler). If you are worried about name-clashes, don't, because any outside code will have to resolve the scope with the actual class name anyways.

I think you simply might have taken the encapsulation idea a bit too far.

Comment: The private typedef is just a synonym to a type that's public anyway, so I didn't think it'd break encapsulation to have a public function reference it. As in, using it doesn't expose any more classes than I already am. Is this reasoning incomplete? I'm using gcc 4.4.3, FWIW.

Comment: A typedef is not like a #define. It is subject to the same access rules as a nested class or member function. The fact that that particular private typedef is a "synonym" of the class' name is irrelevant. The fact that the user code has access to the class doesn't mean it has access to its private typedef, even if that typedef represents the class. That is why it should be public.

Answer (score 0):

When you need an opaque type, use an incomplete class instead (and complete it in your implementation file, not header file).

But in your particular example, it doesn't look to me like an opaque type should be used.